# Listbox RowSource space in sheetname

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I have a problem with RowSource to a ListBox on a UserForm. My Source is a named Range "Project" on a sheet called "Source data".
I have tried "Source data!Project" in the property window, but is does not work because of the space in the sheet name (i assume).

Then i tried this code, but it is returning error....

Please help

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Me.LB_Project.RowSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Source data").Range(Project)

end sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello i found a solution myself.

to add ' around the sheetname in the RowSourcefield in property window.

'Source data'!Project

or

```
Me.LB_Project.RowSource = "'Source data'!" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Source data").Range("Project").Address
```

This solwed my problem with the space in the sheetname